# Error importing ngx-charts to Angular as separate component: error NG8001: 'ngx-charts-tree-map' is not a known element

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I have imported ngx-charts in the way suggested in this link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-tree-map-chart?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

However, I'd ideally like to have each chart as a separate component if I can, so I have added it as its own component which is then imported to a page, which is called tab2.

The relevant files are as follows:

tree-map/tree-map.component.html:

```
<ngx-charts-tree-map
  [view]="view"
  [scheme]="colorScheme"
  [results]="single"
  [gradient]="gradient"
  [animations]="animations"
  [labelFormatting]="labelFormatting"
  (select)="onSelect($event)">
</ngx-charts-tree-map>
```

tree-map/tree-map.component.ts

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
import { single } from './data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tree-map',
  templateUrl: './tree-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree-map.component.css']
})
export class TreeMapComponent {
  single: any[];
  view: any[] = [700, 400];

  // options
  gradient: boolean = false;
  animations: boolean = true;

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#E44D25', '#CFC0BB', '#7aa3e5', '#a8385d', '#aae3f5']
  };

  constructor() {
    Object.assign(this, { single });
  }

  onSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

  labelFormatting(c) {
    return `${(c.label)} Population`;
  }
}
```

tab2.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DatabaseService, Emotions } from './../services/database.service';
import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
import { TreeMapComponent } from './../components/tree-map/tree-map.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class Tab2Page {

  constructor(
    private db: DatabaseService
  ) {

  }

}
```

tab2.module.ts

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Tab2Page } from './tab2.page';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { DatabaseService, Emotions } from './../services/database.service';
import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab2Page }]),
    NgxChartsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [Tab2Page],
  bootstrap: [ Tab2Page ]
})
export class Tab2PageModule {
  arr: String;
  constructor() { }
}
```

tab2.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <app-tree-map></app-tree-map>
</ion-content>
```

App.module.ts (cut down, but added to show I am importing it there too:

```
import { NgxChartsModule} from '@swimlane/ngx-charts'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ModalComponent],
  entryComponents: [ModalComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, FontAwesomeModule, MatDialogModule, HttpClientModule, FormsModule, NgxChartsModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    SQLite,
    SQLitePorter
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

This is the complete error I get. I am unsure why, as I am importing it in every feasible way I could be, as far as I can tell.

```
ERROR in src/app/components/tree-map/tree-map.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'ngx-charts-tree-map' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngx-charts-tree-map' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-charts-tree-map' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Comment: where is declared your TreeMapComponent ? which module?
Btw, why do you put module in "providers", in your app.module ?

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party but since there is no accepted answer to this question, I might as well post what solved it for me in case someone else stumbles on this problem.

For me, the problem was that I declared the "NgxChartsModule" module in my app.module.ts file and then tried to use it in another custom module. **Moving the "NgxChartsModule" to the imports of my custom module solved the problem**.

Answer (score 0):

Use below commands
**npm install**
or
**npm i @swimlane/ngx-charts@13.0.4**

Answer (score 0):

For me, although not obvious from the console output, the issue was in the  .spec.ts file generated by Angular for my own component. This is a workaround rather than a fix, I guess, but I am not using the .spec.ts file anyway, so I'm not fussed.

Add this to the imports of the generated .spec.ts file:

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
```

Then refer to it in the TestBed.configureTestingModule invocation:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
```

(etc)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, which was caused by the `spec.ts` file. I had to add an import for the relevant `NgxGraph` module in the `TestBed.configureTestingModule` function call in the `beforeEach` section of the test file. E.g.,

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        NgxGraphModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });
  ...
}
```

I suppose whatever modules your component depends on also need to be imported in the `configureTestingModule` call for each test.